# In ASP.NET core how do you inject a HttpContext into an extension method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Porting an inherited ASP.NET application to ASP.NET core that used a SqlCommand extension method to implement a pseudo ambient transaction:

```
public static class SqlExtension
{
    public static SqlCommand NewCommand( this SqlConnection c )
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = c;

        SqlTransaction ambientTransaction = (SqlTransaction)
            HttpContext.Current.Items["AmbientTransaction"];

        if (ambientTransaction != null)
        {
            cmd.Transaction = ambientTransaction;
        }
        return cmd;
    }
```

Sql statements that use the ambient transaction are spread throughout the code in hundreds of places.  Since HttpContext is no longer globally accessible, I'd appreciate suggestions:

1) On how get things working temporarily.  Is it possible to inject the HttpContext into an extension method?

2) A pattern to follow as the code is re-implemented that accomplishes the same goal, namely wrapping a SQL transaction around all of the work done in a single http request.

Comment: You can add a `HttpContext` as an argument to the method.

Comment: Good suggestion.  Was hoping to do something along the lines of `public static SqlCommand NewCommand( this SqlConnection c, HttpContext h )` and then call the new extension method from the original.

Comment: Don't use the http context and use an AsyncLocal instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1.Resolve the dependency in the method directly, but I don't recommend it. Although you need as well the `IApplicationBuilder`

```
var httpContext =  (IHttpContextAccessor)app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor))
```

2.Pass the parameter in the method

```
public static SqlCommand NewCommand( this SqlConnection c, IHttpContextAccesor http )
{
}
```

Comment: 3rd option. Don't use extension methods, have this in a new class and pickup `IHttpContextAccessor` via DI

Answer (score 0):

Inject dependency on caller, just pass a parameter of HttpContext in extension method.

Answer (score 0):

[I found elegant solution in this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/a-better-approach-to-access-httpcontext-outside-a-controller-in-net-core-2-1/). First, you create static class AppContext, then configure it in Startup.cs in Configure method. Don't forget to add `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` in ConfigureServices method.